# PostgreSQL : Operator does not exist: Integer < Interval

Tags: sql, postgresql, syntax

I have wrote a query so I can view people who are overdue an order based on their average order dates. The query is to be ran on a PostgreSQL database, and will be executed from a Java process.

However in the line :

```
CASE WHEN 
    (max(date_trunc('day', dateordered))- 
    min(date_trunc('day', dateordered)) ) / 
    count(distinct dateordered) + 5 < 
    date_trunc('day',now()) - 
    max(date_trunc('day', dateordered)) THEN 'ORDEROVERDUE' ELSE 
    null 
END
```

I receive the error message :

*Operator does not exist : integer < interval*

I have read a lot of questions which have a similar issue, but none which seem to fix my particular issue.

If I alter my query to this :

```
CASE WHEN
     (max(dateordered::date) - min(dateordered::date) )/ 
     count(distinct dateordered) + 5 < 
     now()::date - max(dateordered::date) THEN 
     'ORDEROVERDUE' ELSE null
END
```

Then it runs on the database, however I can't get this syntax to work in my process in eclipse.

My understanding of SQL is letting me down. I understand the general reason behind the error, but I am unable to create a solution.

Is there a way of altering this line in a way which removes the error and I can still get the desired result?

Comment: Explain _I can't get this syntax to work in my process in eclipse_

Comment: Does `date(now()) - date(max(dateordered))` work _in my process in eclipse_?

Comment: Ah my comment about eclipse is very misleading, I receive the same 'Operator does not exist : Integer < Interval' error, however when running the exact same syntax on the database, it runs fine.

Comment: `interval '5' day`, maybe? But the error message suggests parens might also be an issue.